# laravel, how to redirect to the best URL

Tags: php, laravel, url, redirect, routes

how can I change or redirect the URL if someone typed a false url, example: domain.com/id/name,
a correct url = domain.com/12/appdev
an incorrect url = domain.com/12/devapp

I want to redirect the url to domain.com/12/appdev if someone types domain.com/12/devapp

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way is just to create another route that simply redirects to the correct route.

Comment: Yeah, that's a different route, not really a typo (thinking mod_speling) of a URI. Would think explicit routes for what you will accept. Curious what alternative you envision.

Comment: @Joas but how do I do to do the redirection

Comment: If you google 'Laravel redirect' the first result is the answer to that question. Please try and google your questions before asking them here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Route::get('12/devapp', function () {

    return Redirect::to('/12/appdev', 301);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to create a default route, that will get anything, trying to find the correct route using some function, then redirect the user, like this:

```
Route::get('/{wrongRoute?}', function ($inputRoute) {
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
    $rate = 255;
    $nextRoute = false;
    foreach($routeCollection as $route) {
        $route = $route->uri;
        //example of function to find the best match
        $routeRate = levenshtein($inputRoute, $route);
        if($routeRate < $rate) {
            $rate = $routeRate;
            $nextRoute = $route;
        }
    }
    return Redirect::to($nextRoute, 301);
})->where('wrongRoute', '.+');
```

One thing here is to be sure that the application will not redirect to protected route. You can try to create a whitelist of possible redirections.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of what [Felippe Duratte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1580044/felippe-duarte) said; I think it would be better to handle this inside the **app/Exception/Handler.php** like this (instead of creating a dedicated catch all route for it):

> Laravel throws a NotFoundHttpException when you visit a route that doesn't exist.

```
<?php

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{

    // ... snipped

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {

            $closestUri = $this->closestUri($request->path());

            if ($closestUri) {

                return redirect($closestUri);

            }

        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }

    protected function closestUri($notFoundUri)
    {
        $availableRoutePaths = [];
        foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route) {
            $availableRoutePaths[] = $route->getPath();
        }

        $closest = null;
        $shortest = -1;

        foreach ($availableRoutePaths as $availableRoutePath) {

            $lev = levenshtein($notFoundUri, $availableRoutePaths);

            if ($lev == 0) {
                $closest = $word;
                $shortest = 0;
                break;
            }

            if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
                $closest  = $word;
                $shortest = $lev;
            }

        }

        return $closest;
    }

    // ... snipped
}
```

Code untested, but something like that should get get the job done.